# Netbeans says property value does not exist

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

According to Oracles own website I am doing this right. But when I I do this in Netbeans I get an error that says: Class does not exist PropertyValueFactory. Is there any way to fix this?

```
    <TableView fx:id = "customerTable"  prefWidth ="270" prefHeight = "400" layoutX = "350" >
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text = "Utility">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />

                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>


        </columns>



    </TableView>
```

Comment: Did you add the appropriate import?

Answer (score 3):

It's OK, you just have to import following:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
```

So, something like this in your FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<... other imports ...>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>


<BorderPane prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="FXMLDocumentController">
....
<TableView fx:id = "customerTable"  prefWidth ="270" prefHeight = "400" layoutX = "350" >
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text = "Utility">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
...
</BordePane>
```

would solve this issue.

Comment: Happy coding, @CodeTurn! :-)

Comment: That works fine! Thanks! I can't understand though why it's not importing `cell.PropertyValueFactory` from the whole package, as in my case I have `<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>`, while I was getting the same error.